# XWIKI velocity script not working

Tags: xwiki

Working on xwiki 9.8 and copy the same code which is written below for velocity macro but its not working .showing some error.
Is there ant per-requisit to run the velocity script.if so let me know.

```
{{velocity}}
Welcome $xcontext.user !
#if($hasAdmin)
you will see the following picture because you are an administrator:
image:picture.jpg
#end
{{/velocity}}
```

In the output it shows the picture which have added.
But it is not showing giving errors.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code but without the errors it's hard to tell.

Comment: Do i need to add some extensions  or jar files for velocity to work.

Comment: I cannot see the added picture. Maybe you are not an admin user and lack "scripting" rights - which are needed to use velocity macros.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to achieve and what is the problem. The code looks fine and it works fine.

If you want to add some error to non-admin users, you should include an `#else` block. Example (including check for guest users on the `#elseif` branch):

```
{{velocity}}
Welcome $xcontext.user !
#if($hasAdmin)
  You will see the following picture because you are an administrator:
  image:picture.jpg
#elseif ("$!xcontext.userReference" == '')
  {{error}}You need to [[login>>path:$xwiki.getURL('XWiki.XWikiLogin', 'login', "xredirect=$doc.getURL()")]] to access this section.{{/error}}
#else
  {{error}}You need admin rights to access this section.{{/error}}
#end
{{/velocity}}
```